# When you use sudo, where does it log by default?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo

When you use sudo to perform root level operations, where does it log to by default on ubuntu?

I don't see entries in syslog.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In RHEL systems and its derivatives, it logs to `/var/log/secure`, and in debian derivatives, `/var/log/auth.log`.